# Does using htmlentitiesdecode render/parse HTML?

Tags: php, html-entities

I have a forum which allows administrators to post HTML.  This is a custom forum, so we're trying to make sure that normal users can still post HTML markup but not have it render.

If I store posts as htmlentities and then show posts with html_entity_decode, will it make it so any html they entered in their post renders and affects the page or will it show the actual markup like

```
<html>
<head>
```

etc..

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I store the post raw, and then just apply `str_replace("<","&lt;",$post)` before displaying. A simple `if` statement checks if it's me posting, and if so it skips the escaping so I can post HTML but other users can't.

More importantly, storing the post raw allows users to edit them exactly how they typed them.